# Facebook profile pics only show up in emulator not in devices using app

Tags: android, facebook

my app which uses the Facebook API to pull in friends profile pics only works in the emulator but when I download the app and use it on a detached device, the profile pics do not show up whether or not I am using WIFI, 3G nor 4G to connect.  here is how I am grabbing the image to display.

```
 profilePic = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + friendId + "/picture?type=large";
 Drawable drawable = LoadImageFromWebOperations(profilePic);
 friendImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

Comment: Can you connect your device to your computer and debug this?  Also, watch the logcat for any errors.  Please update your question with more details, such as any relevant logcat messages, stack traces, and what `LoadImageFromWebOperations()` does.

Comment: after not being able to get setImageDrawable to display the profile pic, I eventually resorted to Facebook's example code which uses setImageBitmap();
  String s = String.valueOf(friendId);
  friendImageView.setImageBitmap(Utility.model.getImage(
                s, profilePic));

Answer (score 0):

Once you sign the app you need to change the Key Hash on the Facebook Development portal. I'm not sure if you pulling down a signed or an unsigned app but that may be the problem.